# shortest path in matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

There are a 30x30 matrix with 0,1,2 elements which are randomized. I need to find the shortest path from the top to the bottom of the matrix. I can move only in 1. I have no idea whats wrong with this.

the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

#define max 30

using namespace std;

int matrix[max][max];
int smatrix[max][max]; ///all elements are 0

int lenght=0; ///út hossza

void showMtx()
{
    for(int i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<".\t";
        for(int j=0; j<max; j++)
        {
            //if(matrix[i][j]==1)cout<<"k ";
            //else cout<<" ";
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";

        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
void path()
{


    for(int i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<max; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i+1][j+1]==1 && smatrix[i+1][j+1]!=1) ///diagonally down
            {
                smatrix[i+1][j+1]=1; ///indicates that the i and j was here
                lenght++; ///step counter
                cout<<"->("<<i+1<<","<<j+1<<")";
            }

            else if(matrix[i][j+1]==1 && smatrix[i][j+1]!=1) ///right
            {
                smatrix[i][j+1]=1;
                lenght++;
                cout<<"->("<<i<<","<<j+1<<")";
            }

            else if(matrix[i+1][j]==1 && smatrix[i+1][j]!=1) /// down
            {
                matrix[i+1][j-1]=1;
                lenght++;
                cout<<"->("<<i+1<<","<<j<<")";
            }
            else if(matrix[i+1][j-1] && smatrix[i+1][j-1]!=1) ///diagonally down up
            {

                smatrix[i+1][j-1]=1;
                lenght++;
                cout<<"->("<<i+1<<","<<j-1<<")";
            }

            else if(matrix[i][j-1]==1 && smatrix[i][j-1]!=1) ///left
            {

                lenght++;
                smatrix[i][j-1]=1;
                cout<<"->("<<i<<","<<j-1<<")";
            }

            else if(matrix[i-1][j]==1 && smatrix[i-1][j]!=1) ///up
            {

                lenght++;
                smatrix[i-1][j]=1;
                cout<<"->("<<i-1<<","<<j<<")";
            }
            else if(matrix[i-1][j-1]==1 && smatrix[i-1][j-1]!=1) /// diagonally down
            {

                lenght++;
                smatrix[i-1][j-1]=1;
                cout<<"->("<<i-1<<","<<j-1<<")";
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if(i==30)break;
        }
    }
}
void shortestPath()
{

    int i=0,j;
    for(j=0; j<max; j++) ///find the first 1
    {
        if(matrix[i][j]==1)
        {
            path();
            break;
        }

    }

    cout<<"\nlepesek szama: "<<lenght<<endl;
}
int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<max; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j]=rand()%3;
            smatrix[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    showMtx();
    cout<<endl;
    shortestPath();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `i-1` and `i+1` when `i = 0` and `i = max-1` (same for `j`)?

Comment: Handle corner cases!!

Comment: Oh, I forget this. Added in plus conditions, but still doesnt work correctly. It takes 470-500 steps

Comment: Should I use while loop instead of for?